# PHP list to an Array to a foreach Joomla Module

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, foreach

I have the following PHP, that needs to take a list of article ids and run it through a function to get them all from the database.

I am very much a beginner in PHP so far I have:

```
list($slide1, $slide2, $slide3, $slide4, $slide5) = explode(" ", $params->get('id'));

$a = array(
    $item => $slide1,
    "two" => $slide2,
//    "three" => $slide3,
//    "four" => $slide4,
//  "five" => $slide5
);

foreach ($a as $k) {
    $args['id'] = $k;
    $item = ModArticleSlider::getArticles($args);
}
```

and the class:

```
class ModArticleSlider {

    public function getArticles($args){
        $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
        $item = "";

        $id = $args['id'];
        if($id > 0){

            $query  = "select * ";
            $query .= "FROM #__content  WHERE id =".$id." AND state=1 " ;

            //echo $query;
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $item = $db->loadObject();
        }

        return $item;
    }

}
```

How would i get it so that instead of specifying $item to have it almost dynamic so that i can get all the selected articles and place them in different variables.. or would i have to place them in a array?

Any Advice/Answers Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am also beginner of PHP.
Please Try this:

```
foreach ($a as $k => $val) {
    $args = $val;
    $item[] = ModArticleSlider::getArticles($args);
    var_dump($item);
}
```

in your class

simply

```
$id = $args;
```

i hope it will help you!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, and possibly more performant as it would require only one database query (versus one for each article), would be to use http://docs.joomla.org/JDatabase::loadObjectList

So, you could instead pass an array of your articles ids as $ids to your class like:

```
public function getArticles($ids){

    if ($ids) {
        $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM #__content  WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $id) . ")  AND state=1 " ;
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

        return $rows;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

$rows is returned as an array so you can then process it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Store the articles into an array, you can try this:

```
$slides = explode(" ", $params->get('id'));
$articleArray = array();
foreach($slides as $slide) {
    $articleArray[] = ModArticleSlider::getArticles($slide);
}

var_dump($articleArray);
```